# IPv6 support for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, log

I know that IPv6 connections work against a Magento via sockets.  However, any feature that logs (or filters if there are any) don't support IPv6.

For example, in logs I see an IP address of 0.0.0.0 for any connections coming from IPv6.

Anyone know if there is IPv6 support on the roadmap?   Maybe in Magento 2?

Comment: Is there even support in php? I mean Magento is logging HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR therefore whatever is in this var should be logged. If there is an IPv6 in it, this should be logged?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt PHP 5 has no issue with it.

Comment: I just noticed that an Order in Magento DOES show a proper IPv6 address.

It is only in "Online Customers" where I see an IP address of 0.0.0.0    I assumed that perhaps that indicated an IPv6 address.

Comment: Here is a manual to change you're settings:
http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.de/2010/02/ipv6-for-online-customers.html I tried, but it dosn't work with Magento `1.9.1.0` Maybe it will help you.